# Clarification for Calculus Question (I don't need an answer, just interpretation)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The question is as follows:

```
Write out the first 5 terms of the power series.
```

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n!}x^{3n+1}$

This is a web-based system and all I get is a single textbox with the following instructions:

```
Box 1: Enter your answer as an expression. Example: 3x^2+1, x/5, (a+b)/c 
Be sure your variables match those in the question
```

Comment: Well, the first five terms are the first five pieces that you add in the infinite sum. Do you understand what the notation $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ means?

Comment: Yes, I know what it means. But since this is a power series and that the series converges for all x, what do I use for x? And how am I supposed to input 5 different terms when it won't let me use a coma

Comment: You add them together.

Comment: $x+3x^4+...$ and so on

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm going to try it

Comment: It worked. Thank you @Prototank!